# why is it it that the record appear even if the the record was not on the category

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-like

Hi guys can you help me with my problem.
when I search other categories it appears the record on my other category what happen. The query shows that it will only search the record if the category is correct.

For example record: catname: IT record from my IT is web my other catname is History record is History123 if i search History as my category and blank on search it will appear all

Here is my code:
I hope you can help me im a newbie in php

```
       <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="searchfield" placeholder="Search for Book Title, Author, ISBN COde or Location">
        <select name="catname" class="searchfield">
      <option>--------Categories--------</option>
       <?php

       $query = "select * from categories";
       $result = $con->query($query) or trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
       $result ->data_seek(0);
       while ($row =$result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
         # code...
        echo'<option>'.$row['catname'].'</option>';
       }

        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="searchmo" value="Search" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
      <h2 class="sub-header">List of Books</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">

          <!--author LIKE '%$search%' or bookcode LIKE '%$search%' or location LIKE '%$search%'
              or -->
          <?php
          if(isset($_REQUEST['searchmo']))
          {
            $catname = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['catname']);
            $search = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
             $query1 = $con->query("select bookname,bookid,bookdesc,location,
              categories.catname,qty,bookcode,copyright,editionnumber,publisher,author 
              from categories inner join books on books.catname = categories.catname
              where  books.bookname LIKE '%$search%' or books.author LIKE '%$search%' or
              books.bookcode LIKE '%$search%' or books.location = '%$search%' or
              books.publisher LIKE '%$search%' 
              and categories.catname = '$catname'") or die(mysqli_errno());
            if($query1->fetch_assoc() == 0)
            {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">No result found.</div>';
            }
            else
            {
            $catname = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['catname']);
            $search = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
            $query = $con->query("select bookname,bookid,bookdesc,location,
              categories.catname,qty,bookcode,copyright,editionnumber,publisher,author 
              from categories inner join books on books.catname = categories.catname
              where  books.bookname LIKE '%$search%' or books.author LIKE '%$search%' or
              books.bookcode LIKE '%$search%' or books.location = '%$search%' or
              books.publisher LIKE '%$search%' 
              and categories.catname = '$catname'") or die(mysqli_errno());
            //$result ->data_seek(0);
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
            {
          ?>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Book Title:<?php echo $row['bookname']?>- ISBN: <?php echo $row['bookcode']?> </strong></h3>
            </div>
              <div class="panel-body" style="line-height:10px;">

                <p>Author: <?php echo $row['author']?></p>
                <p>Publisher: <?php echo $row['publisher']?></p>
                <p>Location: <?php echo $row['location']?></p>
                <p>Quantity: <?php echo $row['qty']?> book's available</p>
                <p>Summary:<?php echo $row['bookdesc']?></p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <?php
          } 
            }
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: `$conn` (`$conn->error`) and `$con` ? which one is it?

Comment: `mysqli_errno()` => `int mysqli_errno ( mysqli $link )` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php

Comment: $con = my connection ing db.php sir

Answer (score 0):

`echo` your query so you can see what it looks like after replacing the variables.

The way you currently have it `LIKE '%$search%'` is going to look like `LIKE '%"searchterm"%'`. Because you are adding quotes around the string ahead of time.

So assign to `$search` like so:  `$search = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);`

**Side note:** you should look in to prepared statements.

Comment: hello sir thanks for the answer it works. I added some query in my code. I have another problem it look like it will run again i added if the user did not found any result it will appear no result found here is my code. I will update my post here kindly answer please